# RandomString Error In Output

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to get this using randomString..

```
function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
}
var rString = randomString(100, '0');
```

I need the output like this..
0
00
000
0000
00000
000000
0000000
00000000
 and so on till 100

Comment: If you need a pre-determined output, then it certainly isn't random. And yes, there is a way.

Comment: Yeah, I just re-read @Grundy; I'm a little confused, though, as to what the question is...

Comment: Im getting 100 zeros :(

Comment: I need a script to get the desired output as mentioned above..

Comment: Your code implies 'chars' is read as an array, what haappens if you try randomString(50,'01')?

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code.
I renamed the function because it is not a randomString function.

http://jsfiddle.net/8rn5gpze/

```
function bar(length, chars) {
    var result ='', last = '';
    for (i = 0; i <= length; i++){
        last += chars;
        result += last;
        result += '<br>';
    }
    return result;
}
var foo = bar(100, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script

```
<script language="javascript">
function randomString(length, chars) {
var result = '';
var i;
var sequencecheck = 1;

var finalresult = '';

for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) 
{
    result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];    
    finalresult+=result
    if(result.length == sequencecheck)
    {
        finalresult += "<br/>"
        sequencecheck++;    
    }
}

return finalresult;
}
var rString = randomString(100, '0');
document.write(rString);
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple output to the console just use this:

```js
function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    
    for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        result += chars;
        console.log(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your output you could use this function: [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jh0hcuut/)

### HTML

```
<div></div>
```

For demonstration purposes.

JavaScript

```
function strTimes(str,times){
    var fullStr = "";
    for( var i = 0 ; i < times ; i ++ )
        fullStr += str;
    return fullStr;
}

function outputZeroes(levels,outputToElement){
    var newLine = ( outputToElement ) ? "<br>" : "\n";
    var str = "";
    for( var i = 1 ; i < levels ; i ++ ){
        str += strTimes("0",i);
        str += newLine;
    }
    return str;
}

var div = document.querySelector("div");
div.innerHTML = outputZeroes(10,true);
```

The `outputZeroes()` function accepts to parameters, the first one is the amount of levels you want, and the second one is a `boolean` that decides which new line should be used, if set to true, it will be `<br>` for outputting to html elements, and if false it will be `\n` for outputting to anything else, by default is false.

Hope it helps!